# Is there a non-religious alternative for "Diable!"?

Tags: phrase-requests

"Diable!" is similar to "What an unpleasant surprise!". What word(s) can I use to convey the same meaning? It should be not religious, understood and hopefully short.

Comment: Is "Ho ve!" close enough?

Comment: @jknappen I think, but some people might disagree (we will see)

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people say *Fek!* It might be considered slightly more offensive, however, depending on your point of view.

Answer (score 5):

"Diable" and "Ho dio" are the only widespread equivalent to the English phrases of mild surprise. "Ho ve" is often heard but is often said with a more disapointed tone, and "fek" is more abrasive and obscene than "diable" or "ho dio". Despite being religious references, neither of them are semantically religious, as you generally aren't actually saying something is of the Devil or calling on God when coming across a mildly surprising situation. They are merely codified expressions.

Answer (score 4):

*Fek!* certainly is useful, just as the slightly longer *kio la fek!?* used (a lot) by Evildea, the famous YouTuber [Kion la Fek' Mi Ĵus Ludis?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEhwBOzexRk)

*Dissaltu!* is translated as "get lost". I have seen *iru kacen* (slavic inspiration) instead of *iru al inferno* on [Telegramo](http://telegramo.org). Simply *kacen* or *bugren* probably work too...

Otherwise I like *fulmotondro!* because it is neither obscene nor religious. (Unless you would attribute it to Thor or some other mythic thunder god.)

Less simple and longer is *Aktoj de la Akademio!* and it is neither obscene nor religious. I recently used *sable!* while I was at the beach, but that is hardly widely understood or used. Otherwise *Ho ve!* certainly does work, but it isn't a swear word - if I had just left it at that, this answer would be pretty boring.

If you look at [this wordlist](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/Insults_from_A_to_F) you can certainly find what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't really like *kio la fek* as it looks like a word-for-word translation from English. It seems to me grammatically incorrect. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know. Looks like another StackExchange question is needed! :-D

Comment: Aux oni povas kompreni tion kiel: "Kio estas tio feko?" sed ne diru tion entute, cxar vi estas tiom surprizita.

Comment: I agree with @Lyobornir, _kio la fek'_ is a literal translation from English and, in my opinion, incorrect

Comment: Klf (kio la fek' kiel popularigita de Evildea aŭ kio la fik' kion mi jam longe antaŭ tio uzis) estas ŝerca esprimo kiu nun pro Evildea sufiĉe populariĝas kaj pro tio estas uzebla. Ĝi certe ne estas gramatike ĝusta, sed tio estas ankaŭ ĝuste la ĉarmo en la originalo...

Comment: The English phrase usually has an f-word with a different meaning than fek', so I wouldn't say it is a word-for-word translation unless you change the "e" to an "i" :)  Also, the English phrase is also not grammatically correct or is at best a fragment (there is no verb, the swear word is not used in a verb sense here).  It is really "What is going on?" with "is going on" left unsaid and a swear word stuck in.  One does not need to be grammatical when swearing.

Comment: To add another point: anything understandable in Esperanto *is* Esperanto. (looking for the exact place to quote... can't find it... will create new question.)

Comment: "Kio la fek'" although maybe not a word for word translation of the English phrase, is obviously an anglicism, and a rather superfluous one at that. I think we can keep the use of superfluous fragmented phrases who's meaning is not obvious to non-english speakers (or with insufficient exposure to English) to a minimum.

Answer (score 4):

It's more like a sound effect, but perhaps "Aĉ!"

It's not offensive, not religious, and conveys an unpleasant opinion of what is being observed.

Answer (score 4):

*Terure* is a good choice - as is *ho ve*.

I wonder, though, what you mean by "non religious." Even "golly", "jeeze", and "gosh darn it" are religious in origin.

Most blasphemes are based on religion, sex, or poop. In English, I prefer to swear on Mother Hubbard and Mother of Pearl Inlay - which are ultimately religious references. I also swear on "sons of motherless goats" which is probably a sexual reference, ultimately. How far removed to these references have to be not to count as religious in your book.

For my part, I don't consider *damne* and *diable* to be religious, even though it is clearly more religious than Mother Hubbard. (Oh, and let's not forget "hell's bells" - which I say all the time without thinking of hell.)

You could go with a sarcastic *vere belete!*

There is probably no end to the made up expressions you could use. I often express surprise with *sankta bolak!* a reference to an early Idist. *Zamne* from elsewhere in this thread is very clever and worth using.

Answer (score 2):

"*Damne!*" is also quite common. Not sure if it has a religious reference.

Comment: Since ReVo gives this explanation: "Kondamni al la suferoj de la infero." it is most certainly religious. It is probably so that it is so commonplace today that we don't perceive it as religious, even though that is the original meaning. (well, unless you see hell not as a religious but a philosophical concept, one could argue, I guess.)

Comment: Maybe instead of "Damne!" you can say "Zamne!"

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this is used at all. But *terure* should carry the same meaning without being religious. You may sound "foreign" when using it, because it isn't commonly used in my experience, although it should be perfectly understandable.

Comment: I would suggest trying to confirm whether something is used before answering.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular is **Fek** (Poop). I also think a good one would be **Damne** (Damn). Or, a very light one would be **terure** (terrible).